# How can I view a .kml or .kmz file on a mobile device offline?

Tags: kml, mobile, kmz

I need to view a KML/KMZ file on a mobile device in a remote area where there will not be service.  I have downloaded applications that have maps of the area; these maps will be available offline. However, I don't think they have a capability to import the KML/KMZ file.

What can I do to make these files accessible without pulling data from the network?

Keep in mind I also need GPS capability (all the mapping apps I've downloaded have it, so this shouldn't be a problem).

If that's not possible, can I save the text of the KML/KMZ and at least have that on my mobile device (IPhone 5)?

Comment: what mobile device? there are different workarounds for different types of devices.

Answer (score 1):

The kml/kmz will be available offline, unless it is a network link.
You will probably want to get an aerial or basemap of some kind and create on image overlay kml. This will let you have basemap data.
Qgis works well on android and would allow data (of your own). You still would need a basemap clipped to your area of interest.
Answer the device question and you will find some more help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  The device is an iphone 5 - is Qgis available for that?  I dont have a true base map, the only maps I have are from several apps that work offline.  Any idea where I can get a base map?  THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Map Plus. I think it's based on iOS maps and not Google, but it's pretty good.

Comment: As it stands you answer looks too brief to be useful.  I recommend that you edit it to provide a link to the software which you are suggesting answers the questions but especially add some details about *how* it answers the question.